# Trying to make a ban command for my discord bot but when i run the command i always get an error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is the code I made for the ban command

```
Crashbot.on('message', message => {

    //looks for args if the user types a message with the defined prefix     
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    //the switch equals true if the first arg (word) after the defined prefix is "ban"
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ban':

        //checks if the message author has the needed permission to ban members
        if (message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {

            //checks if a user was mentioned to be banned and if not says that you need to specify someone to ban
            if (!args[1]) message.channel.send('You need to specify a person !');

            //makes a constant called user and sets it to the first person mentioned in the message
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();

            //checks if the constant "user" is a user mention
            if (user) {
                const member = message.guild.member(user);

                //checks if the mentioned user is a member of the guild (the discord server)
                if (member) {
                    
                    //checks if there was anything typed after the user mention (second arg) if not bans the mentioned user and responds with successfully banned "user" 
                    if (!args[2]) {
                        member.ban("Banned by Crashbot").then(() => {
                            message.reply(`Successfully banned ${user.tag}`);

                        }).catch(err => {
                            message.reply('I was unable to ban that member');
                            console.log(err);
                        });

                        //checks if there was anything typed after the user mention (second arg) and if there was ban the user and responds with successfully banned "user" for "reason specified in second arg"
                    } 
                    else if (args[2]) {
                        member.ban(`${args[2]}`).then(() => {
                            message.reply(`Successfully banned ${user.tag} for ${args[2]}`);

                        }).catch(err => {
                            message.reply('I was unable to ban that member');
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
});
```

and this is the error I keep getting in the console

```
Response: Internal Server Error
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Michael\desktop\crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:158:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/555146022490341476/bans/615261605860737035'
}
```

the bot doesn't crash and the code is returning with the error and continuing to run like intended but I don't understand why I keep getting this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try to put complete options ? (I'm not sure if it's gonna work, but let's try)

```
// ban a guild member
guildMember.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

[Documentation #ban](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: That doesn't mean you should put it as an answer.  It means you should build up reputation first.